# Problem placing ContentPlaceHolder within <script> tags

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2008

I have this in an ASP.Net Master Page:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="scriptContentHolder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </script>
```

But when I try to view the content page in design mode it tells me there is an error in the associated Master page because "scriptContentHolder" does not exist.

```
<asp:Content ID="scriptContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="scriptContentHolder" runat="server">
    g_page = "mnuSurveys";
</asp:Content>
```

If I change the Master page to this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="scriptContentHolder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

and the content page to this:

```
<asp:Content ID="scriptContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="scriptContentHolder" runat="server">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    g_page = "mnuSurveys";   
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Then all is cool. Why is this? The page compiles and executes just fine... but as above the designer squawks when placing ContentPlaceHolder controls within  tags.

Comment: Seeing ASP control defined inside of a Javascript block makes me cringe. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/360416/asp-net-designer-does-not-recognise-asp-contentplaceholder-inside-client-side-script-block) MS Connect posting as of May '09, the

> VS designer doesn't support controls
>   within script blocks. Alternately, you
>   can call
>   Page.ClientScriptManager.RegistgerClientScriptBlock
>   from content page

[sic]

So you'll have to use the second/work around method you posted.

Comment: Or the `RegisterScriptBlock` method mentioned in the quote.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and solved it like that:

```
<%= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" %>    
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // On document ready, execute this methods... 
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="jQueryOnDocReady" runat="server" />                 
    });
<%= "</script>"%>
```

Comment: With this solution VS doesn't complain about an invalid masterPage: so, thank you for the solution... however I see a bunch of text (the javascript commands, that should be invisible) in the designer view... any way to solve also this new small visual problem caused by this solution?

Answer (score 0):

this may be a bit off track. But I was having the same issue because i had some generic code i wanted in my Master page, and other more specific only on certain pages, here is my solution:

-In my .Master:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PerPageScript" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

-In my .aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PerPageScript" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This would definitely work in most cases, but in my case, I had to have a content placeholder directly in my javascript $(document).ready(function(){}); function, and thus resorted to @Ascher's method above.